# Linking external web page within the jquery app

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.in" rel="external">Search</a>
```

When I click this link, the browser pops to the front instead switching to the page. I have created the navigation bar in all pages with back button. But when I click the Search button google page opens external and I am unable to get back to the app.

How can I link to an external page in a way that it still looks like one app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this.. but try setting the target attribute to `_self` like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.in" rel="external" target="_self">Search</a>
```

Read more about HTML5 [browser context names here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#browsing-context-names).